# AMD Phenom II X6 1040T can't dissipate the heat

Tags: cpu, cooling, desktop-computer, temperature

Recently, I began to have thermal throttles with my CPU. About a year ago I had the stock cooler and paste, when I noticed that the CPU temp gets high. After that I replaced the heat sink with a bigger one, and it seemed this issue is solved, but a few day ago I began to have the same issue. I have dusted out in depth the cooler, and replaced the thermal compound with a new one, to hope if it was the problem, but it isn't. The CPU seems to heats up very quickly, and cools down so slow, if the thermal compound wold be the issue, or like so. It ran on stock 2.8 GHz clock, and I have underclocked it to 2.5, so It wasn't overclocked at all.

- It's an AMD Phenom II X6 1040T CPU - according to specs and CPUID the dissipation power is 95W
- with ARCTIC COOLING Freezer 13 - according to specs it is able to dissipate 200W of power, so its way over sized, for sure
- inbetween a Cooler Master HTK-002 paste

The strange is, both the cooler and the heat pipes are cold, and doesn't seems its unable to dissipate this much heat. I think it has to do something with the thermal compound, or the CPU itself. I'm suspicious of the last one.

Edit 1:
(I forgot the temperatures) According to SpeedFAN and the BIOS the CPU operates at 45-65 °C, and as I put it under load, it gets all the way up to 90-95°C.

Comment: What makes you think it's a thermal problem, you don't give us, any operating temperatures

Comment: I've added the temps; I heats up very quickly, and cools down so slow.

Comment: Did you check that the cooler is properly seated and you applied the right amount of paste?

Comment: There is a vague possibility that the thermal material between the CPU die and the metal can heat spreader has gone bad or has a gap. I'm not advocating "delidding" your CPU as it can damage your CPU but it may be your only choice. An example of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArYIt.jpg

Comment: Heat pipes can leak... that would make the entire cooler fail. [idk how you would check for that, but a visual check for damage/leak staining would be first guess]